# Unpacking bytes to int

Tags: python

I'm new to struct module and I'm trying to do something like this:

```
value = myClient.mySocket.recv(4)
struct.unpack("I",value)
```

Getting value from my server and then unpack it to integer, I'm receving the value but it won't unpack giving me this error:

```
struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 4
```

EDIT:
Ok, so as Martijn Pieters told me there is nothing stored in `value` whne exception is thrown, but there is another part of my code

```
value = myClient.mySocket.recv(4)
struct.unpack("I",value)
if value == 2:
   #do smth
```

And I saw in the debugger that `value` recieved `b'\x02\x00\x00\x00'` but the unpack doesn't change it to `int` so the if statement doesn't execute and in another loop iteration server sends nothing and there is exception. How to unpack this byte value to integer?

EDIT2: Ok I solved it

```
value = myClient.mySocket.recv(4)
value = struct.unpack("I",value)
if value[0] == 2:
  #do smth
```

Comment: So what type of object is value then instead? Did you actually receive 4 bytes?

Comment: When searched for it in a debugger it says : `b'\x01\x00\x00\x00'`

Comment: That is a bytes object of length 4 and won't throw that exception. When the exception is *thrown*, what is then contained in `value`? Note that the `recv()` call **may** return fewer bytes, if that is what is available.

Comment: Ok when the exception is thrown there is `b''` because server is not sending anymore, but there is other problem to it, I have edited my originall question

Comment: `struct.unpack()` **returns** the result.. A `bytes` object is *immutable*, nor can it just be replaced by a function with a completely different type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unpack()` returns the result, so `x = unpack(...)`, then `if x[0] ==...`.